# Magento 2 REST API to generate coupon code

Tags: rest-api, magento-2.2.5

I want to create coupon code in magento 2 using rest api. Any custom module available for create coupon code.

Answer (score 2):

here is the documentation for crating a coupon via rest API:

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/salesRuleCouponRepositoryV1/salesRuleCouponRepositoryV1SavePost

let me know if you need any further assistance !

Comment: I checked swagger link but not understand how to add condition of discount like 5 percent.

Comment: First you need to create a sales rule, then use it in you coupon creation ! Although I don't think it supports % discounts ...

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/salesRuleRuleRepositoryV1/salesRuleRuleRepositoryV1SavePost

Answer (score 1):

This is Magento2 core-functionality

```
<route url="/V1/coupons/generate" method="POST">
    <service class="Magento\SalesRule\Api\CouponManagementInterface" method="generate"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_SalesRule::quote"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

Comment: plz share rest api url  with body

Answer (score 0):

Here is the REST API if anyone still needs it.

```
POST    -   <host>/rest/V1/coupons/generate      =   https://vaseemansari.com/rest/V1/coupons/generate
Auth    -   Bearer Token = ###

Body    -     

{
    "couponSpec": {
        "rule_id": 1,   // make sure that existing rule was created with "Use Auto Generation" (use_auto_generation) = true
        "quantity": 5,  // no of coupons to generate
        "length": 5,    // character length of coupon excluding prefix/suffix. ie = EY-QRF7J-WA
        "prefix": "EY-",
        "suffix": "-WA"
    }
}
Response


[
    "EY-JV6PB-WA",
    "EY-DOL22-WA",
    "EY-XYPBS-WA",
    "EY-PQ0BJ-WA",
    "EY-67146-WA"
]
```

If you need the REST API to create salesRule, just let me know. I would be happy to provide that.